# I have a DB table,and i want to group by and spilt data

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Here is my table

```
======================================
| Name |  goods | Description       |
======================================
| Ada  | A    | It is A .           |
| Ada  | B    | It is B .           |
| Ada  | C    | It is C .           |
| May  | D    | It is D .           |
| May  | E    | It is E .           |
| John | F    | It is F .           |
| John | G    | It is G .           |
| Peter| H    | It is H .           |
| Peter| I    | It is I .           |
| Yo   | J    | It is J .           |
| Yo   | K    | It is K .           |
```

So,I would like to make the output looks like this:
Ada A It is A . B It is B . C It is C .
May D It is D . E It is E .
John F It is F . G It is G .
.
.
.
Until the last of row.
I tried to use :
SELECT * FROM `TBL_NAME` GROUP BY `Name`

it doesnt work but just show 
Ada A It is A .
 May D It is D

I am doing it with PHP and phpmyadmin, Thanks a lot.
Thanks for the answer.

 In extra,how can i echo the query to php?
Here is what i have done:

```
$sql = 'SELECT Name, GROUP_CONCAT(concat(goods, " ", Description) SEPARATOR " ") FROM TABLE_NAME group BY Name';
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Name: " . $row["Name"]. " - Group: " . $row["???????"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

what should i put in ??????, or I am doing wrong in all of it

Answer (score 1):

Use below query

```
SELECT Name, GROUP_CONCAT(concat(goods, " ", Description) SEPARATOR " ") as Final_Description FROM TABLE_NAME group BY Name
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in additional, how can I echo this query to php?

Comment: one more question, can "Final_Description" change to longtext?

Comment: @H.Leung - yes, you can